# Windows non-responsive during Remote Desktop connection

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, freeze

This is Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

I use the command *mstsc* to establish a Remote Desktop connction to a remote server.

The login window shows up, and **while** I'm entering the password the system almost freezes.

Each character of the password takes 3 or 4 seconds to be accepted, and all other opened programs are not accessible.

This behavior tends to happen only the first time I use *mstsc*. If I used it again moments later, everything is normal.

Whar can be the cause of this problem?

[image]

Comment: This is very interesting. Just to check: can you reproduce this each and every time you start rdp afresh or is it a hit and miss thing? I ask because normally user-space software cannot easily cause the system to lock up. Hardware and drivers are more likely to be the cause.

Comment: It happend always when I start mstsc for the first time. Then, if I press *Cancel* and open again (even without entering a password), it seems like the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

While you are entering the password the first time (where it is taking seconds between each character entry), is the whole system "slow" or is it just remote desktop?  Can you switch to notepad and type quickly?  What about your CPU usage at this point in time (high\low)?

Comment: During the password entering, the whole systems is non-responsive. Alt-tab doesn't work.

However, a few seconds later (20 to 30) everything look normal again (even without closing the ''mstsc'' login window).

Comment: Can you try it again with Windows in "Safe mode with Networking" to see if that works ok?  (It should)

Comment: Also, does this happen with ANY machine you are trying to get to the first time?  Can you try a different machine the first time?

Comment: One last idea, can you upgrade to RDP 8.0 (the latest version via an optional update via windows update).  You can check the version by clicking the upper left symbol on the opening screen and clicking "about".